# How to out put a specific letter from a user typed phrase

Tags: java

Forgive me if I do not use the correct terms. I am just starting to learning programming and not having  it easy.

My goal was to create a window so the user can input a phrase (sentence). Then input a number between the length of the phrase and 0. Then have the letter at that specific index displayed.

I am stumped on how to get the letter displayed from a user chosen number.

What I have so far is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

 String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a phrase");
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Length of your phrase is " + phrase.length());
 String index = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number less than " + phrase.length()+ " but greater than 0");
 int num = Integer.parseInt(index);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number is " + index);     
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Character at" + index +" is " + index.charAt(num));
 }
```

I continue to get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

I am honestly lost. I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: do you want phrase.charAt rather than index.charAt ?

Comment: ..........I feel dumb now.......

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I have been staring at netbeans for the last 5 hours over that. Thank you! I just needed a fresh set of eyes

Comment: Not to worry - It happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
string.charAt( selectedIndex );
```

Where `string` contains your sentence and `selectedIndex` is the number between 0 and `string.length()`.